# How to illustrate non available data points in a different shape using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is there a way to change the shape of the points for missing data in R? I am plotting .csv files like this one in a lollipop style.

```
Name,chr,Pos,Reads...ME_016,Reads...ME_017,Reads...ME_018,Reads...ME_019
cg01389728,chr10,6620395,33.82,41.38,41.38,38.46
cg01389728,chr10,6620410,0,-,-,-
cg01389728,chr10,6620430,0,0,-,-
cg01389728,chr10,6620447,0,-,0,-
cg01389728,chr10,6620478,0,-,-,-
cg01389728,chr10,6620510,28.33,29.85,25.64,28.13
cg01389728,chr10,6620520,0,0,-,0
cg01389728,chr10,6620531,0,-,50,-
```

Using ggplot2, my graphs are created with this:

```
dataset <-read.table("testset",  sep=",",na.strings="-", header=TRUE)
dataset <- subset(dataset, select=c(-Name, -chr))
dataset <- melt(dataset, id.vars="Pos")
dataset$variable <- gsub("\\.\\.\\.","_",dataset$variable)
xaxes <- unique(dataset$Pos)
dataset$Pos <- as.factor(dataset$Pos)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Pos, y=variable,fill=cut(value, breaks=10))) + geom_point(size=4, shape=21) + geom_line() + scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("0-10%","10-20%","20-30%","30-40%","40-50%","50-60%","60-70%","70-80%","80-90%","90-100%")) +
    xlab("CpG Positions") +
    ylab("Sample") +
    labs(fill="Coverage in %") +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),plot.title = element_text(vjust=2),axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5))
```

However, I want to set the shape of the missing points ("-") in the plot to an "x", (shape=4) and show them also in the legend. 
I've tried approaches like:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c(value, NA))
```

or:

```
 scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,4))
```

By default, the "-" are also shown with shape 21 and grey colour. There must be a way to manipulate this? Writing a method like this might be the trick, but how to call it for the whole column?

```
formas <- function(x){
+     if(is.na(x)) forma <- 4
+     if(!is.na(x)) forma <- 21
+     return(forma)
+   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes pretty close, I think.

[image]

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Pos, y=variable,
                    color=cut(value, breaks=10),
                    shape=ifelse(is.na(value),"Missing","Present"))) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="",values=c(Missing=4,Present=19))+
  scale_color_discrete(labels=c("0-10%","10-20%","20-30%","30-40%","40-50%","50-60%","60-70%","70-80%","80-90%","90-100%")) +
  xlab("CpG Positions") +
  ylab("Sample") +
  labs(color="Coverage in %") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),plot.title = element_text(vjust=2),axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5))
```

Change are:

- used color instead of fill, with `shape=19` for points with data
- added `shape` aesthetic to `ggplot(...)` call.
- removed `shape=21` from `geom_point(...)` call.
- added `scale_shape_manual(...)` to define the shapes for `Missing` and `Present`, and turn off the guide label.

I know you wanted filled points with a black outline (it does look better), but when I tried that with the added shape aesthetic, the fill legend does not display the colors correctly. Try it yourself.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Great idea that kind of "overwriting" of shape with colour!

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that comes closer to producing the graph you specified (circular points with black outline and fill color determined by coverage).

```
fill.colors <- hcl(h=seq(15, 375, length=11), l=65, c=100)[1:10]
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Pos, y=variable,
                    fill=cut(value, breaks=10),
                    shape=ifelse(is.na(value),"Missing","Present"))) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Coverage in %",
                    values=fill.colors,
                    labels=c("0-10%","10-20%","20-30%","30-40%","40-50%","50-60%","60-70%","70-80%","80-90%","90-100%"),
                    drop=FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(name="",values=c(Missing=4,Present=21),limits=c("Missing"))+
  xlab("CpG Positions") +
  ylab("Sample") +
  labs(color="Coverage in %") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust=2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=fill.colors),order=1))
```

[image]

The problem in the other answer with using point shape 21 and the fill aesthetic is that, while the fill colors are displayed correctly in the plot, they are not displayed correctly in the legend. One way around that is to force `ggplot` to set the legend fill colors using

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=fill.colors),order=1))
```

Unfortunately, to do that you have to specify the fill colors manually (so that the actual fill and the override fill are the same). This code does that using

```
fill.colors <- hcl(h=seq(15, 375, length=11), l=65, c=100)[1:10]
```

which creates a color palette that mimics the `ggplot` default. You could of course use your own color palette here.

While this does come closer to your original intent, I actually think the other answer provides a better data visualization. The black outlines around the points, while "attractive", make it much more difficult to distinguish between fill colors, especially with 10 possible colors (which is at the edge of discernability anyway).

Comment: I am afraid, the colours are still mixed up and not shown correctly. Thanks for that hint - I haven’t noticed that so far.

Comment: The reason is that cut(values, breaks= 10) do not not scale from 0-100 but from min-max. Thats why the classes goes from 0-5, 25-30, 30-35... 
Changing into cut(values, breaks=c(-0.01,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100) can solve this problem, but now NA is not shown anymore in the plot..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see, why this is not working:

```
fill.colors <- hcl(h=seq(15, 375, length=11), l=65, c=100)[1:10]
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Pos, y=variable
                    ,color=cut(value, breaks=c(-0.01,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
                    ,shape=ifelse(is.na(value),"Missing","Present"))) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  scale_shape_manual(name="",values=c("Missing"=4,"Present"=19),limits=c("Missing"))+
  scale_color_manual(name="Coverage in %",
                     values=ifelse(is.na(dataset$value),"grey",fill.colors),
                     labels=c("0-10%","10-20%","20-30%","30-40%","40-50%","50-60%","60-70%","70-80%","80-90%","90-100%"),drop=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust=2),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5)) +
  xlab("CpG Positions") +
  ylab("Sample") +
  labs(color="Coverage in %") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=fill.colors),order=1))
```

NA values are not shown anymore with an X, and instead of displaying them in "grey", the class 90-100% will be shown in grey. No error message is shown - what is the problem?